# Part Id 3900 take wrong technology id as 7 and it must Be 2 because Feature Name and Value Exist?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, sql-function, dense-rank

I work on `sql server 2017` I have table `#partsfeature` already exist as below

```
create table #partsfeature
  (
  PartId int,
  FeatureName varchar(300),
  FeatureValue varchar(300),
  TechnologyId int
  )
   insert into #partsfeature(PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,TechnologyId)
   values
   (1211,'AC','5V',1),
   (2421,'grail','51V',2),
   (6211,'compress','33v',3)
```

my issue Done For `Part id 3900` it take wrong

Technology Id 7 and Correct Must be 2

Because Feature name and Feature Value Exist

So it Must `Take Same TechnologyId` Exist

on Table `#partsfeature` `as Technology Id 2` .

**correct will be as Below**

```
   +--------+--------------+---------------+-------------
    | PartID |  FeatureName |  FeatureValue | TechnologyId   
    +--------+--------------+---------------+-------------
    |   3900 | grail        | 51V           |   2
    +--------+--------------+---------------+-------
```

**what I try is**

```
 insert into #partsfeature(PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,TechnologyId)
select  PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,
        TechnologyId  = dense_rank() over (order by FeatureName,FeatureValue)
                      + (select max(TechnologyId) from #partsfeature)
from    
(
        values
        (3900,'grail','51V',NULL),
        (5442,'compress','30v',NULL),
        (7791,'AC','59V',NULL),
        (8321,'Angit','50V',NULL)
) s (PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,TechnologyId)
```

**Expected Result For Parts Inserted**
[image: wrong technology id for data exist before]

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/885463/how-to-give-same-technologyid-to-feature-name-and.html)

Comment: can any one help me modify query above to insert partid with correct technology id 2

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS()` to check for existance of `FeatureName` and `FeatureValue`.
Sub query to get existing maximum TechnologyId from table and `row_number()` to generate a running sequence

```
insert into #partsfeature(PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,TechnologyId)
select  PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,
        TechnologyId  = row_number() over (order by PartId)
                      + (select max(TechnologyId) from #partsfeature)
from    
(
        values
        (3900,'grail','51V',NULL),
        (5442,'compress','30v',NULL),
        (7791,'AC','59V',NULL),
        (8321,'Angit','50V',NULL)
) s (PartId,FeatureName,FeatureValue,TechnologyId)
where   not exists
        (
            select  *
            from    #partsfeature x
            where   x.FeatureName   = s.FeatureName
            and     x.FeatureValue  = s.FeatureValue
        )
```